# Image in body of Child page ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: css, asp.net, background-image, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I have a Master Page with 2 different child pages.

One if the child pages i would like to put an background image in. 
This *almost* works however the image does not appear in the **ContentPlaceHolder** it rather appears on the body.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/BiPlanning.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

     <style type="text/css">

body  {
    background-image:url('tmp.jpg');
    <%-- background-size:2px;     <-THIS DOES NOT WORK --%>
}        

   </style>

</asp:Content>
```

I understand what i'm doing wrong however how can i either size my image so it does not cover the whole body of the child page **OR** how do i put the actul image in the **ContentPlaceHolder**?

Comment: Instead of body selector in css why not using the ID="Content2" as selector? Or how this child page is rendered in browser.

Comment: What do you mean with "Instead of body selector in css why not using the ID="Content2" as selector?" OK how?

Comment: <style type="text/css">
#Content2  {
    background-image:url('tmp.jpg');
    <%-- background-size:2px;     <-THIS DOES NOT WORK --%>
}        
   </style> Or what ever is rendered in the browser for that child page, I suppose it will have an ID either Content2 or ContentPlaceHolder1 in the DOM, use one of these as css selector.

Comment: if i remove body {} and replcae it with your code of: #Content2 { background-image:url('tmp.jpg'); this did NOT work

Comment: Inspect in the browser, which element you have in DOM for that "child page" and use a css selector for that.

Comment: i have no ide what "DOM" is i'm pretty new at this but you have my whole child .aspx code?.... Should i put <asp:Content ID="Content2" cssclass="Content" .... > for it to work?

Comment: DOM is the code which is generated after browser parses the HTML code; So more practical, DOM is the code in your browser which you see when using view source. Do you know how to inspect the HTML code in your browser?

Comment: Yes, you can try that, in add cssclass to the placeholder and then use that class name as selector in your css, something like .Content {// your css here } instead of selecting body.

Comment: I have answered my own question :) thank you

Comment: I am glad if I could help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to work i created a DIV tag within my contantplaceholder and changed the width, height etc...

```
<div width="120" height="100" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center" >
        <img src="tmp.jpg" />
    </div>
```